# ARM v7 memory management unit (MMU) ttbr0 and ttbr1

Tags: caching, memory-management, paging, armv7, mmu

In the ARMv7 VMSA MMU, there are two sets of translation tables pointed to by ttbr0 and ttbr1. The range of virtual address that will be used for translation either by tables pointed to by ttbr0 or ttbr1 is set by the 'N' field TTBCR register.

Now, if I set this TTBCR.N to 7, the address range covered by translation table at ttbr0 is 0x00000000 - 0x2000000

So the first address after 0x2000000 (i.e 0x2000004?) will use translation table at ttbr1 for translation. As per short-descriptor format in ARMv7 VMSA, translation tables can have either sections (1MB) regions, supersection (16MB) mapping regions.

My question is what happens if I place a super-section at a address location say, 0x1600000.

According to theory, then the address in the range 0x1600000 to 0x2600000 will be mapped to physical address 0x1600000. (But, this won't work as the translation table itself changes at 0x2000000 ?)

So what happens in this scenario? Also what should be placed at the first entry of ttbr1 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a programming error and page table should not set up like this with address block of one region overlapping with the other.Consider this you have set VA 0x1600000 onwards till 16 MB to be a block of 16MB super section and say that you access the location 0x1600000 ,now your TLB will have a virtual to physical mapping for a 16MB section starting form 0x1600000.Now next say you access the memory location 0x2000000 ,here look up into TLB will happen first and a matching entry will be found ,no page table walk will happen .You might have mapped 0x2000000 onwards to some other physical address space and then such a access will potentially address into unintended location.